# Spring / Intellij: Raw use of parameterized class 'HttpEntity'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to understand a warning in my Spring code.

I have a HttpEntity which is being set to my HttpHeaders, however its getting flagged as a Raw use of the class.

I'm not sure why this is, nor, how to rectify the warning. I know it's only a warning but I'd like to get rid of this.

Can someone shed some light on the why and the how to remove it.

```
    final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    final HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(headers);

    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GitHubService.class);

    @Autowired
    public GitHubService() {
        headers.set("Authorization", gitHubAuthToken);
        headers.set("Accept", "application/vnd.github.VERSION.raw");
    }
```

I'm also getting the same type of warning

```
Warning:(44, 35) Unchecked call to 'HttpEntity(MultiValueMap<String, String>)' as a member of raw type 'org.springframework.http.HttpEntity'
```

Many thanks

Comment: You probably want `HttpEntity<String>`. The warning about the raw type is a warning about missing <>

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. So basically it can't infer the type is that right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add the parameterized type:

```
final HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttyEntity<>(headers);
```

The type is the body of the entity. Probably a string, but depends on how you use it.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you for taking the time to help.